# Windows 7 on HP EliteBook 2730

Tags: windows-7, laptop, tablet, hp-elitebook

I have HP 2730p. A nice little tablet that came with Vista Business.I want to switch to Windows 7. Has anybody done that? Does everything work? I'm asking because of the finger print reader and the pen tablet driver. Does that work? The touch interface on Windows 7, how does that behave with pen based devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no problems with Windows 7.

The [HP website has a full list](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=uk&prodNameId=3784561&taskId=135&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=3784558&lang=en&cc=uk&submit=%C3%82%C2%BB) of drivers you can download for Windows 7 so it is fully supported.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend running the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displayLang=en&id=20), available at the Microsoft Download Center.

Download it , install it, then run it.   It will tell you everything you'll need to know about Windows 7 and the components and software on your system.